# Need silent rewrite URL in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm running tomcat behind apache. now my need is to apply friendly url by removing parameters names from URL. 
i want

```
http://<domainname>/<APPLICATION>/QWERTY
```

these internally should works as

```
http://<domainname>/<APPLICATION>/vid=QWERTY
```

so in tomcat i can get the value of vid and process the request accordingly

for this i tried,

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
 RewriteEngine On    
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !vid=(.*)$ [NC] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/$ [NC]   
   RewriteRule ^/APPLICATION/(.*)$ /APPLICATION/?vid=$1 [R=301,L]    
</IfModule>
```

By applying this the application working when i give `http://<domainname>/<APPLICATION>/QWERTY` but in Browser URL bar the url is changed as `http://<domainname>/<APPLICATION>/vid=QWERTY`

i need `http://<domainname>/<APPLICATION>/QWERTY` to be in browser address also.

**Update :**
By 'Jacek_FH' answers i have updated my rules [removed `R=301` ]

```
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !vid= [NC] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/ [NC]   
   RewriteRule ^/APPLICATION/(.*)$ /APPLICATION/?vid=$1 [L]
```

its giving resource not found exception(404)

so for testing i have changed my friendly url to `http://<domainname>/<APPLICATION>/u=QWERTY` and tried

```
    RewriteRule ^/APPLICATION/u=(.*)$ /APPLICATION/?vid=$1 [L]
```

But this also result in 404 in tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

If you want silent rewrites (URL unchanged in the address bar), you need to use the [[P] flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p), instead of the [R=301,L].

Basically, the request is handed to a proxy server, so the client never sees any changes.

You don't want the client, and especially search engine robots, to do a permanent redirect, so you don't want the [R=301].

The [P] flag includes an implied [[L] flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) (last command), so you want to make sure they occur after any:

- Fall-through rewrites, like removing www., are done as permanent redirects, with the [R=301] flag, but no [L].
- Forbidden [[F] flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f) rewrites, like for image-bleeding protection, are done before these, as it also includes an implied [L].

As mentioned under the [P] flag description in the *apache* documentation, make your *RewriteCond* statements' regexp be specific as to what inputs are processed, and explicitly specify the target URL, so that malicious or erroneous user input will not create improper urls.

Note that the [P] flag prevents connection pooling (uses the default worker thread), so there are no persistent connections, with possible performance loss.

Note that this does not appear to work for https sites, so that the [L] flag has to be used instead of the [P] flag, with no silent redirection. Bummer!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `R=301` as it's moving browser to the new address

You could simplify:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !vid=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/
RewriteRule ^/APPLICATION/(.*)$ APPLICATION/?vid=$1 [L]
```

without `/` on the right part, htaccess flow would not be restarted

`assets` part is needed only for `/APPLICATION/assets/`, not for just `/assets/`, I've removed `$` from the end as it limits matches to plain directory call

Comment: Removing / from rightpart result in "Bad Request" error in Apache. So i tried without removing slash(/) from right part. Now 404(Resource not found) error in Tomcat Application . In Firebug newtowk tracking also every request in Red(404)

Comment: try to use filepath: `RewriteRule ^/APPLICATION/(.*)$ APPLICATION/index.jsp?vid=$1 [L]`